# When wrong PIN CoreBluetooth service trigging connected ok

Tags: swift, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Currently implementing pairing functionality from the app to BLE device using CoreBluetooth framework.

When entering wrong PIN getting delegation, that connection established. As well discovering services for connected peripheral works fine. Could someone explain why entering wrong PIN connection and services discovery works fine?

More detailed steps:

1. Executing connect function from CBCentralManager class.
2. An app show native CBCentralManager PIN entry alert.
3. Entering wrong PIN.
4. CBCentralManagerDelegate calls delegate method did connect. -> Notice: wrong PIN entered.
5. Start discovering services for connected peripheral without any error. -> Notice: wrong PIN entered.

Comment: Is this a custom BLE device that could be configured/programmed incorrectly?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Yes. It is custom device.

Comment: That's strange, but does the characteristic that triggered the pin can be read? If other characteristic are "open", your device can read it without being able to pair.

Comment: @Larme I have spoke with responsible team and confirmed, that it should not be like this. Thanks everyone for support :)